# Convert characters or symbols to existing variables in R

Tags: r, string, variables, character

I'm using R to compute the best fit of a sequence of initializations, and I named them Initialization1, Initialization2, etc.. I compared the best fit with the largest result_probs value. And I want to use the one, say Initialization1, with the best property I want again.

```
best_fit <- paste("Initialization", which.max(results_probObs), sep = "")
best_estimated <- somefunction(best_fit, string1)
```

However, best_fit here is a character and can't be used as the existing Initialization1 (which is a list). I've tried as.name() too. It gave me a symbol and couldn't be used as a list as well.

Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: `get` might get you there

Comment: @baptiste Thank you so much! "get" does solve this problem.